# Iterating over multiple lists of lists in Python

Tags: python, list

```
a= [ [(54, 54, 54), 
     (21, 21, 21),
     (12, 12, 12) ],
     [(22, 12, 22),
     (11, 11, 11),
     (33, 33, 33)] ]  

some_num = 10
for x in range(len(a)):
    b = list(a[x]**[0]**)
    for y in range(len(b)):
        b[y] *= some_num
    a[x] = tuple(b)
print(a)
```

is there a way to make this iterate over more than just the index 0 (bold)? I am curious what would be the best way to approach this. I am also expecting that list to grow so I am really looking for a tip on how to make it iterate for any number of lists.

Thank you,

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: i have those lists of lists that I am trying to multiply by a number without changing the structure of the incoming lists.

Comment: Your list of lists `a` is missing a square bracket somewhere.

Comment: What is the point of having inner lists with just one tuple member?  Just un-nest that one level.

Comment: @roippi you had a valid point. I think i had some extra brackets there. my bad.

Comment: is it really two levels of list? You have `a=[[first_list],[[another_level_deeper]]]` or is it all the same depth?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with this recursive solution

```
def rec(current_item, number):
    if isinstance(current_item, list):
        return [rec(item, number) for item in current_item]
    elif isinstance(current_item, tuple):
        return tuple(rec(item, number) for item in current_item)
    else:
        return current_item * number

a = [[[(54, 54, 54)], [(21, 21, 21)], [(12, 12, 12)]],
     [[(22, 12, 22)], [(11, 11, 11)], [(33, 33, 33)]]]

print rec(a, 5)

# [[[(270, 270, 270)], [(105, 105, 105)], [(60, 60, 60)]],
#  [[(110, 60, 110)], [(55, 55, 55)], [(165, 165, 165)]]]

a = [[(54, 54, 54), (21, 21, 21), (12, 12, 12)],
    [(22, 12, 22), (11, 11, 11), (33, 33, 33)]]

print rec(a, 5)

# [[(270, 270, 270), (105, 105, 105), (60, 60, 60)],
#  [(110, 60, 110), (55, 55, 55), (165, 165, 165)]]
```

Comment: I am getting an unsupported operand type for *: 'List[object]' and 'int' when i run this...

Comment: @user3263488 Then your data is wrong. Can you please post proper data?

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming* that your list is not of arbitrary depth (i.e., **it is a list of list of tuples of numbers**), just step through element by element:

```
a= [ 
    [(54, 54, 54), (21, 21, 21), (12, 12, 12) ],
    [(22, 12, 22), (11, 11, 11), (33, 33, 33)] 
   ]  

num=10
nl=[]
for l in a:
    print l
    nsl=[]
    for t in l:
        print t
        nt=[]
        for x in t:
            print x
            nt.append(num*x)
            print nt
        nsl.append(tuple(nt))   
        print nsl 
    nl.append(nsl)    

print nl  
# [[(540, 540, 540), (210, 210, 210), (120, 120, 120)], [(220, 120, 220), (110, 110, 110), (330, 330, 330)]]
```

(I have the `print` at each level to show you what is happening. Remove to use...)

Since tuples are immutable, you have to produce new ones tuples to multiply each element in the tuple. If you lad a list of list of list on numbers, you could modify in place.

If it is arbitrary depth, use recursion.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a recursive function.

Here is a simple example:

```
a= [
 [(54, 54, 54), 
 (21, 21, 21),
 (12, 12, 12) ],
 [(22, 12, 22),
 (11, 11, 11),
 (33, 33, 33)]
 ]

def go_through(list):
    for x in list:
        if isinstance(x, list): #if is list
            #do something
            go_through(x) #loop again
        else: #if not list
            #do something else

go_through(a)
```

Didn't check it so I don't know if it works but you get the idea...